# use workbox without using cdn

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

Does anybody know how to use workbox without getting it from the CDN?  I tried this...

add `workbox-cli` to my dependencies:

```
    "workbox-cli": "^3.6.3"
```

which gets me all of the following dependencies

```
$ ls node_modules | grep workbox
workbox-background-sync
workbox-broadcast-cache-update
workbox-build
workbox-cacheable-response
workbox-cache-expiration
workbox-cli
workbox-core
workbox-google-analytics
workbox-navigation-preload
workbox-precaching
workbox-range-requests
workbox-routing
workbox-strategies
workbox-streams
workbox-sw
```

Then I replaced this line in the examples

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js');
```

with this

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.js');
```

after copying `node_modules/workbox-sw/build/workbox-sw.js` to the public folder

But now I realise by looking at the network tab, that that file still gets all the other modules from the cdn

[image: network tab]

(I thought it would be build with everything inside it.)

Can anybody tell me if there is an npm package somewhere that already has everything inside it?  Or should I copy the modules I need from the npm folder, and somehow tie them all together myself? Or do I have to use the webpack plugin? (which I guess will only bundle the modules that I use)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**(Update: [Workbox v5](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers) makes the process of using a local copy of the Workbox runtime much simpler, and in most cases, it's the default.)**

There's one more step that's required. The "[Using Local Workbox Files Instead of CDN](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw#using_local_workbox_files_instead_of_cdn)" has the details:

> If you don’t want to use the CDN, it’s easy enough to switch to
> Workbox files hosted on your own domain.
>
> The simplest approach is to get the files via workbox-cli's
> [`copyLibraries`
> command](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli#copylibraries)
> or from a GitHub Release, and then tell `workbox-sw` where to find
> these files via the modulePathPrefix config option.
>
> If you put the files under /third_party/workbox/, you would use them
> like so:
>
> ```
> importScripts('/third_party/workbox/workbox-sw.js');
>
> workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: '/third_party/workbox/'});
> ```
>
> With this, you’ll use only the local Workbox files.

Comment: thanks. `workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: '/third_party/workbox/'});` is what I was looking for.  I still copied them out of node_modules when building so that I can download them the same was as all my other libraries.